# Who to limit a textbox to a list of words, not admitting any other

Tags: textbox

I apologize for my English.

I wanted to know how I can limit a textbox to a list of words, not admitting any other.
Example: {London, Lisbon, Paris, Rome, Madrid}, the user can only type these words.
How to do this...

Thankful for the help

Comment: You need to use `validation` capabilities of your platform.

Comment: So can they type multiple words as long as they fall within your given group? Or should they only type one of those words?

Comment: They only type one words-  just one